# Chart is loaded and disabled immediately after submitting the button

Tags: javascript, charts

I am new to php,js,MYsql.. currently working on generating the chart using Chartjs for no of cases worked for each customer.

please find the my below code.

```
<?php

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "DB", "DB");
$query="select account_name,count(*) as count from case group by name";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$json=[];
$json1=[];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) )
{
extract($row);
$json[]= $count;
$json1[]=$account_name;
}
#echo json_encode($json);
#echo "<br>".json_encode($json1);

?>
<Html>
<Head>
<Style>

</style>
<title>Chart Collection</title>
</head>
<Body>
<form id="formID" class="form-horizontal" method="post"
                name="frmCSVImport" >
Start Date:
                <Input type="date" id="date_start" name="date_start">
                <br> <br>
                End Date:
                <Input type="date" id="date_end" name="date_end">
                <button id="run" type="submit" onclick=make_chart() name="run" >Run</button>
                </form>
<div class="mycharts">
<h3>Customer Cases</h3>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="chart2">
<br>
<h3>Customer</h3>
<canvas id="myChart2"></canvas>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<Script type="text/javascript">
function make_chart()
{

Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily = "'Roboto', 'Helvetica Neue', 'Helvetica', 'Arial', sans-serif";
Chart.defaults.global.legend.position = 'bottom';
Chart.defaults.global.legend.labels.usePointStyle = true;
Chart.defaults.global.legend.labels.boxWidth = 15;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltips.backgroundColor = '#000';
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'pie',

    // The data for our dataset
    data: {
            labels:  <?php echo json_encode($json1); ?>,
        datasets: [{
            label: "Customer Case",
            backgroundColor:[   'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(540, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'],
            borderColor:[   'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'],
            data: <?php echo json_encode($json); ?>,
        hoverBorderWidth: 20,

        }]
    },

    // Configuration options go here
    options: {
     responsive:false,
      maintainAspectRatio: false,
 scales: {          
        }       
    }
});
var ctx2 = document.getElementById('myChart2').getContext('2d');
var chart = new Chart(ctx2, {
    // The type of chart we want to create
    type: 'bar',

    // The data for our dataset
    data: {
            labels:  <?php echo json_encode($json1); ?>,
        datasets: [{
            label: "Customer Case",
            backgroundColor:[   'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(540, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'],
            borderColor:[   'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'],
            data: <?php echo json_encode($json); ?>,
        hoverBorderWidth: 20,

        }]
    },

    // Configuration options go here
    options: {
     responsive:true,
      maintainAspectRatio: true,
 scales: {

        }   
    }
});
}
</script>
<body>
</html>
```

Here after submitting the form, chart is loaded and immediately gets removed from the page.. could you please let me know what i missed in this code...

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: You mean submitting a form ... Well, that's what submission does, it loads a new page from your server. If you actually don't need to execute any server-side code, then don't submit the form, otherwise you've to send the data with AJAX.

Comment: Thanks Teemu for taking.. actually my aim is to get the date value from two date input from after submitting the form.. then pass those value to php to fetch the mysql data based on the start date and end date..   After generating the data from mysql , we need to create chart using that data

Comment: In that case you create another php file, which does the needed DB stuff, and then sends a new page back, which draws the chart.

Comment: Teemu could you please give any sample examples for this to generate the chart.. Because i am new to php,ajax,html.. thanks in advance... Also i want to generate the chart in the same page itself instead of new one...

Comment: ?? You already have the code to create the chart, just save it into another file, no need for AJAX.

Comment: i need to show the chart in the same page itself..is it possible .....

Comment: Not without AJAX if you're going to need some data based on the form from the server to create the chart.

Comment: thanks teemu. able to do perform chart as you suggested.. thanks man once again.